# Google translate - add a line of code

Tags: google-translate

Can anyone please guide me on adding this line of code:

```
$('.link-all').trigger('click');
```

to Google translate:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'de,en,fr',  layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```